# Crystal lang : How to get location of macro itself rather than macro argument.

Tags: macros, crystal-lang

One could get location of a ASTNode via [`ASTNode#line_number`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.25.1/Crystal/Macros/ASTNode.html#line_number%3AStringLiteral%7CNilLiteral-instance-method) and other methods.

However the problem is one can get ASTNode of a macro's arguments but macro itself. Something like `self` in macro isn't defined. The question may be induced to "How to get ASTNode of a macro itself rather than arguments", but I guess it's impossible.

But even for the location of arguments, some just returns `nil` and nothing:

```
macro xx(**args)
    {% p args.line_number %} # => nil
end
xx a: 123
```

You will find `#line_number`, `#filename` and all other location fields are both `nil` for `NamedTupleLiteral` and `TupleLiteral`. Which means macro like `xx` can never get code location? Or, it's just something I missed?

Really thanks.

Comment: Counter question: Why do you need the location of a macro def? What's the use case for this?

Comment: I'm, not sure what you are trying to achieve, but maybe the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` constants will be useful.

Comment: @JohannesMüller It occurs in the error message from macro, like [`Macros#raise`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.25.0/Crystal/Macros.html#raise%28message%29%3ANoReturn-instance-method)

Comment: If you feel it's lacking file an issue and/or bring it up in the mailing list :)